# How to trust a default-certificate

Tags: ssl, certificate

We just connected an alarm-system to our network that should detect physical intrusion into our buildings. To configure the system, I connect to it via https.
Not surprisingly, I do get a certificate warning (untrusted issuer and invalid CN).

Is there any way to make the Window 10-machines on our network trust this certificate for a domain of my choice?

e.g.: The device should be available using https://alarm1.ourdomain.com.

The certificate seems to be a root-certificate, since it does not reference any other certificates.
Some more details:

- Common Name (CN): Secvest
- Organization (O): ABUS Security-Center GmbH & Co. KG
- Country (C): DE
- Organizational Unit (OU): Alarmanlagen

Please find the full public certificate below. For further information you can decode the certificate here: https://redkestrel.co.uk/products/decoder/

> -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
>   MIIDkzCCAnugAwIBAgIEIFXqSDANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADBjMRAwDgYDVQQDEwdT
>   ZWN2ZXN0MSswKQYDVQQKEyJBQlVTIFNlY3VyaXR5LUNlbnRlciBHbWJIICYgQ28u
>   IEtHMQswCQYDVQQGEwJERTEVMBMGA1UECxMMQWxhcm1hbmxhZ2VuMCAXDTEzMDEw
>   MTAwMDAwMFoYDzIwNjAwMTAxMDAwMDAwWjBjMRAwDgYDVQQDEwdTZWN2ZXN0MSsw
>   KQYDVQQKEyJBQlVTIFNlY3VyaXR5LUNlbnRlciBHbWJIICYgQ28uIEtHMQswCQYD
>   VQQGEwJERTEVMBMGA1UECxMMQWxhcm1hbmxhZ2VuMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEF
>   AAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAoRYMhI3iSzlC/bPNoFPn9jc261GQfsyOZZgh+LRlk8kk
>   HQH5jLVmXJuWgulsAr+yZ8/BADxhhwms72SBidS7AwYatoVOy4oFpZ98dbOQ7/oz
>   OV7PGaDb38jaLKIUzQZfSnwVXcFoqpIJ8F5f5ub+EDkW4SWNGs2iZQHbA5GQjlzV
>   lXoJt2CgjU7cjOZLHEZAoxoT7bH+ou6DQzIC4x/LDf9ghWL/HyM/lRsPLuRmEwXd
>   L3psF1gxHqWeDC1+G2O23CEhz6/1yYkCarzDyg97S1y5KC82AVWMjbVdgztOeEdH
>   vhwPX0Q6ZNYtrM8N+BE9fsSyEKbipNuRcLGsuxeQiwIDAQABo00wSzAJBgNVHRME
>   AjAAMB0GA1UdDgQWBBThCBy94Jmop1ms4LzjQSR8iDqrIDAfBgNVHSMEGDAWgBTh
>   CBy94Jmop1ms4LzjQSR8iDqrIDANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFAAOCAQEAmXSALKISQx1J
>   t97twpMWPPtuNeWlGRqPSqFoLcGHvbuK1UuATKv2STHlF0dleeMU3lxyR8WrnRkV
>   UQXp/DbU0Wu7WZ+6XEzF1okC0utbixPDIsjyqNEPfcDqVD2JXYoH4u+jB8RozHGl
>   HMYwrVlAYDaBuye0gxdB71lE8NE/t0IqEJL3tGEZuDoyCmN9x9SVgvKL+gM56Xx/
>   5W8BXP1L0SDTVoOHH8g+iJ4MjGZceQAHSs9/6HUAJeRhYAHZqlq2S324TLDQZuqD
>   mOocT4FtsKg6R6uLOiBAM3ijP3RnBgTziSH8uvWAFX4NrPqKAmVrvLgtx6BHM6Gw
>   zagvSyAMWw==
>   -----END CERTIFICATE-----

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772491(v=ws.11).aspx (basically use a method to import the self-signed cert into the Enterprise Trust store on the computers)

Comment: Thank you. Adding it to the trusted root-certificates is not enough, since it does not contain the correct common name. And how should it, since it has no idea, how our internal domains are called?

Comment: The CN would work if the shortname was "Secvest" on your domain and the users accessed it via that name and not an FQDN of it.  If you've named the site/server something else though you'll need to issue your own certificate (preferred anyway) and upload it to the server using whatever the server requires as the medium to do so (IIS, apache, proprietary software interface).  Check with the vendor of the alarm system if it is possible to change the cert.  Almost always it is.

Comment: Thank you. The vendor claims that changing the certificate is not possible.
We could use "Secvest" to access it. But since we have four of these devices, we would have to use different ports, which would not be very convenient.

Comment: OK, unfortunately that means in the browser on each machine you'll have to accept it each time, because if the CN doesn't match up I don't think adding it as a permanent exception would work either...it will still complain.  Maybe someone else may have another idea short of turning off SSL.

Comment: Take this up with the vendor. Really, it's their problem to solve.

Comment: `The vendor claims that changing the certificate is not possible` -- I'd recommend to switch the vendor. If they can't solve their cert issue -- you are wasting your money with them.

Comment: In addition, I can suspect that they share the same key pair across all devices. If this is the case, then you are fooled.

Comment: For completeness: I just had a telephone-call with the manufacturer "ABUS Security Tech Germany". The response is as clear as it gets: Every user has to accept the insecure connection when accessing the web-interface. There is no way around it. And there is no way to store an exception.
Shame on them for having "security tech" in their name.